# MVC register method broken

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-identity

I am working on a basic MVC project, pretty much out of the box with minor enhancements. I have therefore customized the user properties a bit, but not too much... however, it seems not to be working anymore since then. I've done the exact same before without running into errors. Any ideas where I went wrong??

IdentityModels:

```
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //public string                               UserName                            { get; set; }
    public string                               FirstName                           { get; set; }
    public string                               LastName                            { get; set; }
    public string                               Gender                              { get; set; }
    public string                               DateOfBirth                         { get; set; }
    //public string                               Email                               { get; set; }
    public string                               PhoneNumberPrefix                   { get; set; }
    public string                               PhoneNumberSuffix                   { get; set; }
    //public string                               PhoneNumber                         { get; set; }
    public bool                                 PhoneNumberVerified                 { get; set; }
    public string                               BillingAddress                      { get; set; }
    public bool                                 BillingAddressIsShippingAddress     { get; set; }
    public string                               ShippingAddress                     { get; set; }
    public string                               VATNumber                           { get; set; }
    public string                               PreferredLanguage                   { get; set; }
    public DateTime                             RegisteredDateTime                  { get; set; }
    public string                               RegisteredLatitude                  { get; set; }
    public string                               RegisteredLongitude                 { get; set; }
    public string                               RegisteredLocation                  { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class UserDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public UserDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    public static UserDbContext Create()
    {
        return new UserDbContext();
    }
}
```

AccountController:

```
// POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        // define variables
        var userID                                              = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        DateTime nowUTC                                         = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        DateTime nowLocal                                       = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
        // check model state and submit form
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user                                            = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName                                        = model.UserName,
                FirstName                                       = model.FirstName,
                LastName                                        = model.LastName,
                Gender                                          = model.Gender,
                DateOfBirth                                     = model.DateOfBirth,
                Email                                           = model.Email,
                PhoneNumberPrefix                               = model.PhoneNumberPrefix,
                PhoneNumberSuffix                               = model.PhoneNumberSuffix,
                PhoneNumber                                     = model.PhoneNumberPrefix + model.PhoneNumberSuffix,
                BillingAddress                                  = model.BillingAddress,
                VATNumber                                       = "MwSt-Nummer",
                PreferredLanguage                               = model.PreferredLanguage,
                RegisteredDateTime                              = nowUTC,
                RegisteredLatitude                              = model.RegisteredLatitude,
                RegisteredLongitude                             = model.RegisteredLongitude,
                RegisteredLocation                              = model.RegisteredLocation
            };
            // send confirmation email
            var result                                          = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                string code                                     = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl                                 = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new
                {
                    userId                                      = user.Id,
                    code                                        /*= code*/
                }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Bestätige Dein Konto", "Bitte bestätige Dein Konto indem Du <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">hier</a> klickst.");
                ViewBag.Message                                 = "Fast geschafft! Du hast eine Email mit weiteApplicationDbContextren Instruktionen erhalten um die Anmeldung abzuschliessen.";
                // track user activity: post method includes activity name and timestamp along with location
                var SUCCESS                                     = new UserActivities
                {
                    UserID                                      = userID,
                    ActivityName                                = "Register_Success",
                    ActivityTimeStampUTC                        = nowUTC,
                    ActivityLatitude                            = model.RegisteredLatitude,
                    ActivityLongitude                           = model.RegisteredLongitude,
                    ActivityLocation                            = model.RegisteredLocation
                };
                DATADB.UserActivityList.Add(SUCCESS);
                DATADB.SaveChanges();
                return View("PostRegistration");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        var FAILURE                                             = new UserActivities
        {
            UserID                                              = userID,
            ActivityName                                        = "Register_Failure",
            ActivityTimeStampUTC                                = nowUTC,
            ActivityLatitude                                    = model.RegisteredLatitude,
            ActivityLongitude                                   = model.RegisteredLongitude,
            ActivityLocation                                    = model.RegisteredLocation
        };
        DATADB.UserActivityList.Add(FAILURE);
        DATADB.SaveChanges();
        // repopulate dropdownlists
        ViewBag.gender                                          = DATADB.GenderList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text                                                = m.Gender,
            Value                                               = m.Gender
        }).ToList();
        ViewBag.countryCode                                     = DATADB.CountryCodeList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text                                                = m.CountryCode,
            Value                                               = m.CountryCode
        }).ToList();
        ViewBag.preferredLanguage                               = DATADB.LanguageList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text                                                = m.Language,
            Value                                               = m.Language
        }).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention the actual error - mostly because I am not sure where I go wrong.. but what I've noticed is that at the result.Succeeded part it indicates 'false' - but I am not sure why.

Comment: Define `not to be working anymore`? also that formatting - my mind is blown

Comment: I solved it.. I had to set userID = model.Email and it works just fine.